# Library like AsyncTask for Long-Running task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have used `AsyncTask` for short operation tasks in my android application, Now I want to implement a same thing for Long-Running task - Is there any same library with same interface?

BTW please do not suggest `Service`, because I want to update my UI after tasks get done!

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: And what is wrong with AsyncTask itself ?

Comment: @M.Sameer As I mentioned above according to Android docs `AsyncTask` is not design for long running operations.

Comment: Use an `AsyncTaskLoader` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to implement a same thing for Long-Running task

That depends on the nature of the "long-running task".

- If it is something that will last less than a second (usually), stick with `AsyncTask`.
- If it something that will be more than a second but less than 15 seconds, use an `IntentService`.
- If it is something that will be more than 15 seconds, but will end on its own after some longer number of seconds, use my `WakefulIntentService`, or the combination of a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentService`. These are necessary to help keep the device awake while the work is going on.
- If it is something that will only end when the user indicates that it should end (e.g., by pressing some "Stop" button in your UI), use a `Thread` managed by a regular `Service`, perhaps also carefully using your own `WakeLock` if needed.

> Is there any same library with same interface?

Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

> BTW please do not suggest Service

If the task will run long enough that an `AsyncTask` is inappropriate, then by definition a `Service` is essential.

> because I want to update my UI after tasks get done!

There is nothing stopping you from updating your UI when a long-running task completes. Use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus). Or, use a `Messenger`.

Bear in mind that with any "long-running task" that your UI may no longer exist when "tasks get done".

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a `Service` that notifies the UI after a task has been completed.

The actual work of the long running task will still have to be done on an AsyncTask as Service runs on UI thread. Your chances of the system killing your task is just lower than when doing the work on an Activity.

I do this by setting a callback from the Activity using the binder after the service has connected.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html for details about binding Activity to service.

This will only work if your Service and Activity is on the same process. (This is the default setup)

Comment: AFAIK services are usually run in UI thread, I'm not sure about this approach!

Comment: Yep, it does. You'll have to use both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1) You can use `AsynkTask` for long-running tasks as well. 
If you wish to run multiple tasks at a time you can use AsyncTask's `executeOnExecutor(...)` method with `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as first parameter

2) `Service` (`IntentService` for async). 
To update UI you can use `Intent` & `BroadcastReceiver` classes.

Example:

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity that will get your task finished callback

In activity when you want a long task to begin you simply call `startService()` supplying it with `Intent` to your `IntentService` with action & extras already set.

In `IntentService` in `onHandleIntent()` you check action, extras of incoming intent and launch your desired task.

After task is completed you simply call `sendBroadcast()` with an `Intent` that will trigger `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity

That's it. If that is difficult you should check out how Intents, BroadcastReceivers & Services work